# Question about the argument type of sqrt and round

Tags: haskell, types

following the signature:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

why is `(sqrt 2)` legal? Isn't the number `2` a Integer which definitely doesn't satisfy Floating? Same Question about round, `round (sqrt 2)` is legal, sqrt returns type Floating but round needs ReadFrac.

```
round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Comment: `round (sqrt 2)` works because `sqrt 2` returns a Double? `typeOf (sqrt 2)` returns Double

Comment: `2` can take any `Num` type, so `Integer`, but also `Float`, `Double`, etc.

Comment: In many other languages, numeric literals like `2` are of type `int` and any `int` value can be "promoted" as needed to other types. Consequently, if `x` is a `double`, an expression like `1/2*x` is zero since division happens before propotion. In Haskell there is no promotion at all: all conversions need to be done manually. However, numeric literals like `2` are polymorphic and fit the type needed from the context. In Haskell, `1/2*x` with `x :: Double` means `(1::Double)/(2::Double)*x` so the result is not always zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal `2` is of type `Num a => a`. That is, it can be any numerical type. Specifically, Haskell will take the integer value `2` and call `fromInteger` on it (which is defined for any `Num`). So when you write

```
sqrt 2
```

Internally, what's happening is

```
sqrt (fromInteger 2) :: Floating a => a
```

And if you force the value, such as in GHCi, you'll get a `Double` since that's the [default](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) for `Floating`.

Likewise, the type of `round (sqrt 2)` is going to be `Integral b => b` and is going to require the `sqrt 2` type to be `RealFrac a => a`. There exist types which are both `RealFrac` and `Floating`, so that's not a contradiction. In particular, GHC will happily default to `Double` here for the same reason as before. If you force the value to be printed, the entire result (`Integral b => b`) will default to `Integer`.

It's important to remember that all of these are universally quantified. `Floating a => a` doesn't mean "this is some floating type and that's all I know". It means "if you have *any* floating type, I can produce a value of that type". You get to *choose* which floating type to use, so if a constraint comes along later and says the value is also `RealFrac a => a`, that's fine because we've simply constrained ourselves to be both `Floating` and `RealFrac`. This is contrary to a language like Java, where if I have a value of some interface type, say `Comparable`, then all I can conclude is that it's *some* `Comparable` type, not that it works for all of them.